# Comparing value similarities in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have 3 columns in Excel that I'm trying to compare against.

E.g.
[image]

I want to make sure that the email address should be more similar to Enquirer Name than it is to Client Name.

My current formula looks at if Enquirer Name differs to Client Name, then show me email addresses that match more than 5 characters with Client Name, which doesn't quite eliminate enquirers related to clients where their email address satisfies the equation.

Is Excel capable of returning something like Enquirer-Email match 9 characters, Client-Email match 5 characters, therefore no need to alert. Whereas if it's the other way around, conditional formatting to highlight the line?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't tried it, but maybe fuzzy lookup could be helpful in this case https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011